# Why does Firebase always download all data?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a question multiple answer application. There are about a thousand questions. I grouped them separately. But when I run the application and enter any question group, I think it downloads all the question groups, it downloads all the data. This will mean that my limit is filled very quickly. Can you help me overcome this problem?

[Database Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z1RP.png)

[Firebase Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0f0O.png)

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJjIs.png)

```
myRef.child("SETS").child(category).child("questions").orderByChild("setNo").equalTo(setNo).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                list.add(snapshot.getValue(QuestionModel.class));
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see that Firebase is downloading all questions, and not just the ones matching your query condition, you're probably missing the necessary index in your server-side rules. The database server needs such an index, otherwise it can't perform the order/filter, and will just send all data to the client instead (which will then order/filter).

For you, that index would look something:

```
"SETS": {
  "$category": {
    "questions": {
      ".indexOn": "setNo"
    }
  }
}
```

*For full documentation on adding indexes to your rules, see [indexing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).*

With these rules the Firebase server will created an index under `questions` of all `setNo` values of the child nodes, and use that to order/filter.

Comment: [error](https://i.hizliresim.com/AGQDvX.png) I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. Don't we change it this way? I would be glad if you can help a little more clearly, sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading the whole category. Read one at a time.

```
myRef.child("SETS").child(category).child("questions").child(setNo).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                list.add(snapshot.getValue(QuestionModel.class));
            }
```